# GStreamer x264enc not found

Tags: ubuntu, x264, libx264, gstreamer

I installed GStreamer-0.10 and all modules (base, good, bad, ugly, ffmpeg) according to these instructions (browse through by clicking prev/next):
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/multimedia/gst-plugins-ugly.html

Everything seemed to have worked just fine but when I want to execute my pipeline I got this error:

```
glib.GError: no element "x264enc"
```

Apparently the module was not installed:

```
gst-inspect x264enc
No such element or plugin 'x264enc'
```

After that I installed the codec by executing:

```
sudo apt-get install x264
```

This did not work either. So I installed the latest build manually:
http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html

After a successful installation of x264 I ran ./configure on the gstreamer-0.10 ugly modules once again and found out about this:

```
configure: *** checking feature: x264 plug-in ***
configure: *** for plug-ins: x264 ***
checking for X264... no
configure: No package 'x264' found
configure: *** These plugins will not be built: x264
configure: creating ./config.status
```

A check if x264 is available seems to get fullfilled:

```
which x264
/usr/local/bin/x264
```

I'm using ubuntu server 12.04 LTS. Any ideas what I have to do to compile this module properly? Thanks!

Comment: I am getting this same error in CentOS. I tried installing the ugly plug-in using this command "yum install gstreamer1-plugins-ugly-free" but I am stuck with the same error.    Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was that x264 was not properly installed. I checked the x264 source directory and the installation destinations and some files were missing. After manually copying them into the respective directories recompiling the gstreamer ugly module worked.

Comment: Care to share which files were missing?  
I have the packages gstreamer1-plugins-ugly, gstreamer1-plugins-ugly-free and gstreamer1-plugins-ugly-free-devel installed in my fedora distribution, but when I try to inspect using gst-inspect-1.0 x264 but it says there's no such element.  
The only thing that is found which might be that is video/x-h264.

Answer (score 16):

Try to install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.1-plugins-ugly
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 14.04 and gstreamer-1.0. For me, it helped to additionally install libx264-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libx264-dev
```

Comment: This is required when building Ugly plugins from source also.